# How do i make a word (in column A) automatically show a corresponding value (in column B)

Tags: formatting, conditional-formatting

Can someone please explain how i can make a word (typed in column A1) automatically show a corresponding value (in the next column B1), ensuring that any line this word is typed on, in the first column, results in an automatic, predetermined value as a response, in the next column.

Comment: Hi @OOT, you might need to give more input on what you are trying to do..  There are many ways to do something like this - however it might not be suitable for your situation.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text - [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question.

One way to answer as the Q is worded at this writing:

To get a COPY of the value in A1, in B1, if A1 is not empty:
Put this in B1,
`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)`

Copy B1 down into all cells in B-column.

Result: Any filled-in cell in column A will also be shown in column B.

---

Question still "unclear". What is it you're trying to achieve?
There are many ways to display `25` based on the content of A1.

With this in B1,
`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",25)`
... B1 will show `25` if there is anything in A1;
so if you type `Paper` in A1, B1 will show `25`, anything else in A1 and B1 will be blank.

Change B1 to
`=IF(A1="ON","",25)`
... and the EXACT word `ON` will make `25` appear in B1

Yet another way:
`=IFERROR(=CODE(A1)-64;"")`
Will show the numerical "code" of the first char of anything typed into
A1;
so an initial `A` will show `1` and a `Y` will show 25.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Hannu. I meant to ask: I have two columns (A&B). If i type a word in column A1 - say Paper, i want to have a value show automatically in column B1 - say 25. Can you please explain how to do that.

Comment: ... so, added more hints.